# bash: Variable name directly followed by other parameters?

Tags: bash, variables

My bash scripts has a variable `$c` which is called within a `sed`-line, *directly followed by another parameter* - and bash (actually fairly logical) seems to think that the *other parameter* belong to the variable name, rendering it useless/empty.

```
(...)
c=$(printf "%02d" $(echo "$i+1"|bc))
sed -n "$cq;d" /var/www/playlisten.txt|cut -c 4-
(...)
```

The first line sets a temp variable, then it is called as a sed argument. I need to show bash that `$c`ends after the c and that the variable is not named `$cq` (which is empty, of course)...

Any ideas would be highly appreciated, as always.

Thanks,
Christian.

PS. What I'm trying to accomplish :) with this is having a for-loop that steps thru 00..50, within the loop the number itself is needed but also the number +1. Just in case anyone want's to know.

Comment: stupid, stupid me. inserting one line into the other did the trick:
    sed -n "$(printf "%02d" $(echo "$i+1"|bc))q;d" /var/www/playlisten.txt|cut -c 4-

sorry for bothering any of you... ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `${c}q` to prevent the greedy treatment (`bash` trying to use as many valid characters as possible):

```
pax$ export cq=111

pax$ export c=222

pax$ echo $cq
111

pax$ echo ${c}q
222q
```

---

I should also mention that, if performance is important to you, you want to try and minimise how many external processes (like `bc`) you run to do your task. Forking and exec'ing are not cost-free actions and you'll run much faster if you get `bash` to do most of the work itself for short lived tasks.

By short-lived I mean things like adding one to a variable. Obviously if you want to do a *big* job like `sed` an entire file, you're better off doing that in a dedicated external tool but `bash` provides quite a bit of power to replace expensive operations like `i=$(expr $i + 1)` or `i=$(echo "$i+1"|bc)`.

A `bash` loop can be done thus with the increment and other calculations being handled without external processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((count = 0; count < 10; count++)) ; do
    ((next = count + 1))
    echo "count is ${count}, sed string is '${next}q;d'."
done
```

This outputs:

```
count is 0, sed string is '1q;d'.
count is 1, sed string is '2q;d'.
count is 2, sed string is '3q;d'.
count is 3, sed string is '4q;d'.
count is 4, sed string is '5q;d'.
count is 5, sed string is '6q;d'.
count is 6, sed string is '7q;d'.
count is 7, sed string is '8q;d'.
count is 8, sed string is '9q;d'.
count is 9, sed string is '10q;d'.
```

You could also incorporate `next` into the `for` loop as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((count = 0, next = 1; count < 10; count++, next++)) ; do
    echo "count is ${count}, sed string is '${next}q;d'."
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the variable name in braces:

```
c=$(printf "%02d" $(echo "$i+1"|bc))
sed -n "${c}q;d" /var/www/playlisten.txt|cut -c 4-
```

Answer (score 2):

bit shorter

```
sed -n "$(printf "%02d" $((i+1)))q;d" /var/www/playlisten.txt|cut -c 4-
```